# Automatically trigger operations when creating collections

Tags: mongodb

I know that Mongo creates things on the fly. But I would like to have a server side script, and each time that a new collection is created Mongo will automatically execute that script or set of operations.

The idea is that my application code can be unaware of indexes and sharding configuration etc.

Can I do such thing, and if so, how?

Comment: Do you mean the basic data set importing ?

Comment: The script with some predefined collection and their index creation. I want it to be like a 'trigger' on new db creation event, and be saved in mongo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered this over on the Google Group: http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/94d19658299f6bcc

The question is quite vague, but I took a shot at it anyway - try being a bit more specific in terms of what you are trying to do and you may get better responses.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such functionality. Implement something inside your application code.

Comment: Well yes, one possibility is to use some init script on deploy some of bash script. mongoimport -d blog -c user init.js

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach to this is that you [check whether a collection exists](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.7.2/com/mongodb/DB.html#getCollectionNames%28%29) prior to performing any ISUD (insert, select, update, delete) against them.  It seems a bit sledgehammer though.  I'm not sure how you would know what index to apply to an arbitrarily named collection though, unless you are taking some free text from some user input and executing that against you mongo install?  If you're looking to verify the db structure against an 'expected' structure, then you  could [Testing your document structure for inconsistencies](http://exceptionallyexceptionalexceptions.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/testing-your-document-structure-for_12.html)